# How to work with classes and dependences in ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have changed this question to better reflect what it is I do not understand.
For example if I try to access the methods in the railties class AppBuilder.

```
require 'rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator'
g = Rails::AppBuilder.new
puts g.rakefile.inspect
```

I get an error message activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/secure_random.rb:5:in `': uninitialized constant SecureRandom (NameError)

I do not understand this. Should not each class be "independent" from other classes? Is that not the whole point of object oriented programing? 
And now If it is not so more importantly how can I figure out what dependences I need to add?  Is it some kind of workflow to solve this? Can I somehow figure out what dependencies to add looking at the documentation? Do this problem have something to do with load path? Can I load all dependences from a gem or rails or whatever? I just don't get it!

doc: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/AppBuilder.html github: https://gist.github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb

Answer (score 2):

there is no easy way to find out which dependencies are used within `AppBuilder`, cause most of the dependencies are setup somewhere else. so most of the times you need to do some trial and error to get the dependencies right.

the code that you posted has bad style. please get familiar with how to write ruby code properly. buy yourself a book i.e. eloquent ruby or just start reading ruby blogs.

dependencies in ruby is quite simple. every file that you require will be loaded and the load will recurse through the files and then load other requires. the loading will only work if all the required files are on the `load path`. this load path is similar to your system path and you can add directories to it to tell ruby where to look for files.

in general, there are dedicated entry-points for libraries and their dependencies. those are normally documented, so that if you use them, you get all dependencies right from the beginning. an example for this would be to `require 'rails'` in order to use rails or `require 'active_support/all'` if you just want to use active-support. if you wan't to chery-pick files/classes than you are on your own finding out which other classes you need. that part has nothing to do with oop, it's more an dependency-issue (other languages have explicit decleration of dependencies).

in your case, the next step would be to add `require "securerandom"` to the beginning of your file and then check wich error comes up next.

Comment: I don't get this. The whole point with OOP is that it should be easy to extend classes. No? The question is how to figure out what files a class depends on like in this example. trail and error to find the dependences? how?

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer! but should really like to know how you should do in the example above to find out what dependences to add in a effective way. This kind of things I find difficult to grasps from books and blog posts.

Comment: I changed my question to make it more clear, I do not understand what you want me to do. Please help : )

Comment: I still have some issues grasp this but I am reading the eloquent ruby book now (thanks for the recomendation) so maybe I will find answers on my questions. If not I will edit this question one more time : )